# uWSGI won't reload, restart or let me run service

Tags: django, wsgi, uwsgi

I have a fairly big issue.

I am very new to uwsgi and am not 100% sure on how to debug this issue but I will give you information on where I am at.

- I have previously had sites working on this configuration and suddenly it isn't working.
- I am running Emperor mode.
- My ini files are ok when I use command line to run them but it seems they wont automatically start

When I run `uwsgi reload`

```
sudo service uwsgi reload
```

I get this error

```
* Reloading app server(s) uwsgi
...fail!
```

Thats it. I get nothing else.

I have been looking for hours on stack overflow and haven't found anything that outlines this problem exactly, I found a lot to do with peoples .ini files but I know that is NOT my issue because when running my site manually via `uwsgi --ini MYINI.ini` then accessing it it runs perfectly fine, the issue is in uWSGI and I don't know how to find the solution to this one. I have looked in the documents and can't find anything on this particular error.

If  this interests anyone here is my uwsgi-server.conf file

```
description     "uWSGI Emperor"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

env LOGTO=/var/log/uwsgi.log
env BINPATH=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi

exec $BINPATH --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --logto $LOGTO
```

Any insight would be appreciated. I feel like I am missing something but being so new with uWSGI I cant even guess as to what it may be, To me this all looks ok as per the documentation.

If you need any more information on my setup please just ask.

Comment: have you tried running /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals to check if it works well ?

Comment: What version of uwsgi?

Comment: @roberto yes it works fine
@ Louis 1.9.x

Answer (score 85, accepted):

## Use uwsgi the right way

Using uwsgi to deply django site on ubuntu server is quite easy, but there are still something you need to know before making mistakes.

## install

You have two ways to install uwsgi on ubuntu: apt-get or pip

### apt-get

if you use apt-get, you need to install the python plugin:

```
sudo apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python
sudo apt-get install uwsgi
```

And, in your uwsgi ini file for your site, you need to add this:

`plugins=python`

### pip

if you use pip, you need to install python-dev first:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo pip install uwsgi
```

And, you don't need the `plugins=python` in ini file anymore.

See the sudo before pip? Yes, uwsgi should be installed in global system.
If you miss the sudo here, you may install it in your virtualenv.
It's meaningless and you may have trouble running it.

## daemonize uwsgi

Daemonize means make uwsgi run on system boot and in the background.
According to how you install uwsgi, you have two ways.

### apt-get

When you `apt-get install uwsgi` on ubuntu, it's installed as a service automatically. The magic lies in this file:

```
/etc/init.d/uwsgi
```

Files in `/etc/init.d` will be loaded by sysvinit. Then you can manage your uwsgi service like this:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/uwsgi start|stop|restart|reload
```

or:

```
sudo service uwsgi start|stop|restart|reload
```

the service command can find the service managed by sysvinit

### pip

If you uwsgi is installed by pip, you only have the executable file in `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi`, you need to daemonize it yourself.

When you open some of the files in `/etc/init.d/`, you may feel sad:
I just want to register uwsgi as a service, why I need to write such long a script which looks similar to the others? It doesn't make sense.

Good news is that it is quite simple with the help of Upstart, which is an alternative to sysvinit. It use `/etc/init/` instead of `/etc/init.d/`.

Just create a file `/etc/init/uwsgi.conf` with following content:

```
description "uWSGI Emperor"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals/ --logto /var/log/uwsgi.log
```

and then, you can manage your uwsgi process like this:

```
sudo initctl start|stop|restart|reload| uwsgi
```

or, still this:

```
sudo service uwsgi start|stop|restart|reload
```

Yes, as you can see, the service command is smart, it can manage service from both sysvinit and Upstart, with the same command.

And, if you have both `/etc/init.d/uwsgi` and `/etc/init/uwsgi.conf`, when you say:

```
sudo service uwsgi restart
```

It will restart the Upstart file `/etc/init/uwsgi.conf`.
The sysvinit one will be ignored, or something similar.

## uwsgi config for your site

I recommend everyone to use the pip and Upstart way, it's much better then the apt-get way.

If so, you are using the emperor mode of uwsgi, which is very handy and powerful.

Now, you can create a ini file in `/etc/uwsgi/vassals/` like this:

```
[uwsgi]
virtualenv=/path/to/venv/
chdir=/path/to/proj/root
module=wsgi:application
env=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
master=True
vacuum=True
socket=/tmp/%n.sock
pidfile=/tmp/%n.pid
daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

The `%n` means your file name. For example, my project name is 'example', I create a `example.ini` file for it. Then the `%n` means 'example'. You don't need to replace it with real name. uwsgi will do this for you.

And then restart or reload uwsgi:

```
sudo service uwsgi restart
```

Check your socket file:

```
ll /tmp/*.sock
```

If it's there, you are successful with uwsgi now:)

## nginx config for your site

Take domain example.com for example:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     www.example.com;
    return          301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    charset utf-8;
    server_name example.com;

    location  /static/ {
        alias  /path/to/static/;
    }

    location  /media/ {
        alias /path/to/media/;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @django;
    }

    location @django {
       uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/example.sock;
       include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

restart nginx, you will see your site!

## answer to you question

Your config file for uwsgi is `/etc/init/uwsgi-server.conf`
So, the name you should use is `uwsgi-server`, not `uwsgi`

you need to restart your uwsgi emperor instance like this:

```
sudo initctl restart uwsgi-server
```

or:

```
sudo service uwsgi-server restart
```

That's all!

Comment: Using pip, 2 files installed: `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi` and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uwsgidecorators.py` (if we ignore the five meta data files for the egg package). Using apt-get app 220 files installed :) In a sense I like that apt-get takes care of so much, on the other hand the pip setup is much more transparent and it's possible to understand how it works.

Comment: Hi. I wanted to ask one thing, related to installs.  Maybe you can help.
When uwsgi is installed using pip for some reason it does not see default python paths in system path on ubuntu. So in order for it to work you need manually copy all those default paths which are in sys.path to PYTHONPATH. Otherwise you get import error. But when installed by apt-get there is no such problem.  Any idea how to fix this without dirty tricks like adding all those paths to PYTHONPATH through .bashrc?@guoqiao

Comment: Why is it 'wrong' to have uwsgi runing in venv? And could you elaborate a bit more on emperor mode vs venv? Thanks

Comment: Your idea of "uwsgi in venv is bad" is not correct. In fact, running inside venv is recommended and makes the venv truly virtual. Correctly configuring upstart or systemd is the key.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit that removed all content. There are better ways to handle the situation, especially with such a highly upvoted post.

Answer (score 0):

tool for uwsgi restart based on sample app stack: Flask/uWSGI/NGINX from tutorial:

https://iotbytes.wordpress.com/python-flask-web-application-on-raspberry-pi-with-nginx-and-uwsgi/

GIT:
https://github.com/mmossak/uwsgi_restart.git

Saves some time and makes the task fairly easy. Just make sure that you customize script with your application set up(especially starting uwsgi). It only restarts uWSGI.

App used for my Raspbery Pi project interacting with Temperature Sensor which is able to send GET requests to raspberry.

Changing Ini files, touch, sudo service uwsgi restart methods etc. won't help with this. uWSGI in my case isn't a service. It is daemonised process.

You need to kill uwsgi master proces and start again to be able to see changes in application.