# Using uWSGI service started by another user is not restarting with my changes to Django admin

Tags: django, uwsgi

I am running a Django admin site using uWSGI service.  A colleague setup the server, and did much of the initial work.  Now that I am managing the project, I'd like to restart the service including updated code.  I have used the command `sudo service uwsgi restart`, which returns:

`uwsgi stop/waiting
uwsgi start/running, process 19854`

The website runs fine, but with an older version of the code when my colleague last started the server.  If I do `sudo service uwsgi stop`, the site returns a 502 error.  When restarting, the website runs again with the old code and none of the new changes in django admin.py are reflected in the site.

Fixes I've tried are:  Clear the cache and tried removing all the .pyc files prior to restarting.  I also tried starting from a new virtual environment.

How can I make the server run from my virtual environment, using code under my user?

ADDED:  using nginx

Comment: What's the rest of your server environment? Apache, nginx/gunicorn?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing this answer:  [uWSGI won't reload, restart or let me run service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073829/uwsgi-wont-reload-restart-or-let-me-run-service)

I took a look at the *uswgi.conf* file, and also found these instructions for setting up the service, evidently followed by my colleague:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Turns out the *uswgi.conf* file and */etc/uwsgi/sites/[].ini* file were setup with his user, and thus was using the codebase in his virtualenv, e.g.

```
[uwsgi]
project = firstsite
base = /home/user

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application
```

So, I need to run uWSGI setup in my user to fix and restart the server successfully.