# uwsgi with Django, why have a system wide installation of uwsgi, and how does it integrate with sourcecode?

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

*PS, thought quite a bit about whether to put this on SO or SF, its quite a blurry line IMHO, check prev edits to see full explanation.*

The question...
I have followed the official uwsgi docs to successfully deploy a nginx/uwsgi/django stack. The step I don't understand why is:
[Install uWSGI system-wide](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#install-uwsgi-system-wide)

Why does one need to install it system wide for deployment? Why cant the deployment just call my virtual env? If I need the system wide installation (I use supervisor so that could handle loading the venv uwsgi at startup), why do I need the virtual env version of uwsgi (is it only for dev purposes)? I dev on a different machine, and use djangos dev server to test with, so I don't need venv uwsgi?

The reason I am faced with requiring to understand this is I was running the stack on ubuntu, which comes default with python 3.6 and it all worked. Now I am trying to upgrade my project from python 3.6 to python 3.7, and I the system wide installation (with uwsgi) is python 3.6, so it fails when trying to call my python3.7 project.

Then additionally I found one can install uwsgi via apt-get:
[SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23097138/5506400)

I don't understand the relationship of the installed uwsgi to default python version, and to an additionally installed python version (e.g. 3.6, and 3.7). The relationship between the apt-get installation version and what python version that is using and my virtual venv python version.

How should it all tie together, and how to have ubuntu with Python 3.6, virtual env with django & python3.7, and use uwsgi?